# Cannot change row value in datagridview

Tags: c#, linq, datagridview

```
  void refreshtable()  
    {
        var query = (from x in de.HeaderTrainingAllocations
                     join y in de.MsTrainings on x.TrainingID equals y.TrainingID
                     join z in de.MsUsers on x.UserID equals z.UserID
                  select new
                     {
                         x.AllocationID,
                         x.TrainingID,
                         z.UserName,
                         x.TrainingStartDate,
                         TrainingEndDate = System.Data.Objects.EntityFunctions.AddDays(x.TrainingStartDate, ((y.TrainingDuration - 1) * 7)),
                         y.TrainingDuration,
                         x.Capacity
                     }
                     );//get all data from tables
        dataGridView1.DataSource = query;




          for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.RowCount; i++)
          {
              int currentcapacity;
              Int32.TryParse(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[6].Value.ToString(),out currentcapacity);

              String idA = dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value.ToString(); //read allocation ID on cell 0
              var cek = (from x in de.DetailTrainingAllocations

                         where x.AllocationID==idA
                         select x).Count(); //to get amount of data in table detailTransaction

              dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[6].Value =currentcapacity- cek;//this code won't change the value of the rows in datagridview
          }
    }
```

This code is working perfectly but the last code didn't work for some reason,the values in row X at column 6 didn't change at all. I have almost no solution for this in my mind.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 0):

This is the most direct conversion, although you really should be doing a JOIN on DetailTrainingAllocations, rather than making a loop, doing one query for each record.

```
 void refreshtable()  
    {
        var query = (from x in de.HeaderTrainingAllocations
                     join y in de.MsTrainings on x.TrainingID equals y.TrainingID
                     join z in de.MsUsers on x.UserID equals z.UserID
                  select new
                     {
                         x.AllocationID,
                         x.TrainingID,
                         z.UserName,
                         x.TrainingStartDate,
                         TrainingEndDate = System.Data.Objects.EntityFunctions.AddDays(x.TrainingStartDate, ((y.TrainingDuration - 1) * 7)),
                         y.TrainingDuration,
                         x.Capacity
                     }
                     ).ToList();//get all data from tables
          foreach (var z in query)
          {
              var cek = (from x in de.DetailTrainingAllocations
                         where x.AllocationID==z.AllocationID
                         select x).Count(); //to get amount of data in table detailTransaction

              z.Capacity-=cek;//this code won't change the value of the rows in datagridview
          }

        dataGridView1.DataSource = query;
    }
```

Comment: thanks for make it better code,anyway at foreach line there is a problem
where condition only check the allocationID from table cek itself ,so everytable will have the same capacity

Comment: Lol.  I accidentally used the same variable name in the loop and the LINQ query...fixed.

Comment: i got new error at "z.CurrentCapacity-=cek"
it says 

" 'AnonymousType#1' does not contain a definition for 'CurrentCapacity' and no extension method 'CurrentCapacity' accepting a first argument of type 'AnonymousType#1' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)" 

oh and anyway,where should i get the value of CurrentCapacity?

Comment: Sorry, you called it CurrentCapacity in one place, but Capacity in the Anonymous object.  I've updated the answer to always use Capacity, although it would be just as easy to use CurrentCapacity everywhere as well.

Comment: sorry for my bad codes that makes you confused... anyway i got new error 
http://imageshack.com/a/img908/6929/x2mIZk.png...